# Can't disable css caching and aggregation

Tags: theming, caching

I've recently installed some modules including wysiyg, ckeditor, ajax comment, b2 nice comments.

I then noticed that my css files became cached and aggregated when inspect my pages.
I unistalled all the modules and double checked the options in the performance menu which were correctly disabled.

The weirdest thing is that I restored the files and DB to an older version and it didn't help.
I ported the site to another directory within the server (under a different domain) and the problem disappeared.

Anyone with similar experiences or ideas as to what might be the cause ?

Comment: Are there any Caching mechanisms lke Varnish installed on the server ? Also did you tried to flush cache :)

Comment: Indeed, it was the web host's caching mechanism. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Does your theme use the core Color module? I believe that module compiles and caches CSS files with the updated color values whenever the theme color pallet is changed. Just an idea.

Comment: I found quite cases online where it was a module or a theme that hard coded the css caching. 
But it wasn't in my case. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. It turns out it wasn't drupal at all. My web host introduced an extra option to optimise page performance, which was ticked by default when you visted their control panel page by default. Very sneaky.

I guess the moral of the story is to remember that there drupal is not the lowest layer in your website !