# Why are the CSS files in my .info not applied (scripts work fine)?

Tags: javascript, theming, .info

I have a list of CSS files from a premade theme called artifical reason

they are listed in my .info file as such

```
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/preload.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-aqua.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue2.css
```

..... Et Cetera for all the files in the assets/css/ folder

I also have scripts listed in the info file

```
scripts[] = assets/js/app.js
scripts[] = assets/js/carousels.js
scripts[] = assets/js/coming.js
scripts[] = assets/js/coming2.js
scripts[] = assets/js/commerce.js
```

et cetera

I have the style and script variables in my html.tpl.php

```
<?php print $styles; ?>
<?php print $scripts; ?>
```

However, when I go to my site the styles are not applied and there is no reference to them in the HTML. There IS however reference to all the scripts as seen below

```
<script src="http://WEBSITENAME/sites/all/themes/SITEDIREC/assets/js/app.js?nqtizi">
```

I get a couple style sheets being pulled from modules, but most of the CSS left is pulled from this

```
<link media="all" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Does anyone have ideas on why this is not working? I am fairly new to Drupal, so I'm proobably overlooking something fairly major.

I should have mentioned it before: I have cleared cache many times, and turned the CSS/JS aggregation on and off to see if it would work with no success.

Here are the errors i get when i launch the site

```
[Thu Jul 02 08:34:40.847061 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3816:tid 416]        mod_fcgid: process 5448 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Thu Jul 02 08:34:46.941527 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3816:tid 416] mod_fcgid: process 7124 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Thu Jul 02 08:34:50.401630 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 3816:tid 416] mod_fcgid: process 2324 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Here is the FULL info file

```
name = ART REASON sub-theme
description = based on artifical reason
core = 7.x
base theme = bootstrap


 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 ;; Regions
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 regions[navigation]     = 'Navigation'
 regions[header]         = 'Top Bar'
 regions[highlighted]    = 'Highlighted'
 regions[help]           = 'Help'
 regions[content]        = 'Content'
 regions[sidebar_first]  = 'Primary'
 regions[sidebar_second] = 'Secondary'
 regions[footer]         = 'Footer'
 regions[page_top]       = 'Page top'
 regions[page_bottom]    = 'Page bottom'
 regions[social]            = 'Social'



 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 ;; Stylesheets
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/preload.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-aqua.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue2.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue3.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue4.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-blue5.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-fuchsia.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-gray.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-green.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-green2.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-green3.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-green4.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-green5.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-orange.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-orange2.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-orange3.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-pink.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-red.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-red2.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-red3.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-violet.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-violet2.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-violet3.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-yellow.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/style-yellow2.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/vendors.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/width-full.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/width-boxed.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCore.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreDefaulter.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreDjango.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreEclipse.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreEmacs.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreFadeToGrey.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreMDUltra.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreMidnight.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreRDark.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeDefault.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeDjango.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeEclipse.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeEmacs.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeFadeToGrey.css
 stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeMDUltra.css
stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeMidnight.css
  stylesheets[all][] = assets/css/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeRDark.css



;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; JS
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

scripts[] = assets/js/app.js
scripts[] = assets/js/carousels.js
scripts[] = assets/js/coming.js
scripts[] = assets/js/coming2.js
scripts[] = assets/js/commerce.js
scripts[] = assets/js/e-commerce_product.js
scripts[] = assets/js/home_full.js
scripts[] = assets/js/home_inverse_navbar.js
 scripts[] = assets/js/home_login_full.js
scripts[] = assets/js/home_plain.js
scripts[] = assets/js/home_product.js
scripts[] = assets/js/home_profile.js
scripts[] = assets/js/home_services.js
scripts[] = assets/js/html5shiv.min.js
scripts[] = assets/js/index.js
scripts[] = assets/js/jquery.min.map
scripts[] = assets/js/lightbox.min.map
scripts[] = assets/js/page_charts.js
scripts[] = assets/js/portfolio.js
scripts[] = assets/js/respond.min.js
scripts[] = assets/js/slidebars.js
scripts[] = assets/js/styleswitcher.js
scripts[] = assets/js/vendors.js





 ; For information on choosing the desired method, please read the Drupal
 ; Bootstrap sub-theme "how-to" documentation:
; https://drupal.org/node/1978010

; ;----------------------------------
; ; METHOD 1: Bootstrap Source Files
; ;----------------------------------
; 
 ; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; ;; Scripts
 ; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; 
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/affix.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/alert.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/button.js'
 ; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/modal.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/popover.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/tab.js'
; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/transition.js'
```

SOLVED: Such a simple problem for how much work I put into trying to solve it. I did not have the correct filepath specified on the .info file, because I thought, incorrectly, that the filepath was relative to the template instead of the .info file. so i had to go templates/assets/css instead of assets/css. I had tried this solution before, but I guess I forgot to clear my cache first. Thanks for the help

-Matt

Comment: Did you convert this into a Drupal theme yourself using Bootstrap Drupal theme as a base? Or is it actually premade for Drupal? I only noticed a WP version is why I'm asking

Comment: A few extra things to check: 1. Physical folder/file permissions 2. Server error logs 3. Watchdog log - admin/reports/dblog Can you post the entire contents of your .info file?

Comment: It is NOT premade for Drupal, and I copied over the files using bootstrap as a base, then replace the css/js/picture files and then changed the info file and inserted my page.tpl.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Such a simple problem for how much work I put into trying to solve it. I did not have the correct filepath specified on the .info file, because I thought, incorrectly, that the filepath was relative to the template instead of the .info file. so i had to go templates/assets/css instead of assets/css. I had tried this solution before, but I guess I forgot to clear my cache first when applying that fix. Thanks for the help

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking the various answers to the question about [Can't disable css caching and aggregation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54951/cant-disable-css-caching-and-aggregation) ... it includes some hints that may help in your case also, such as:

- Try clearing the  cache?
- CSS / JS aggregation turned on?
- Any caching mechanisms (like Varnish) installed on the server?
- Could it be a module or a theme that hard coded the CSS caching?

Since none of these are mentioned in your question, I thought it's worth pointing to them ...

Comment: Yeah i should have mentioned that I have cleared cache many times, and turned the css/js aggregation on and off to see if it would work with no success.