# Why can't I disable CSS caching?

Tags: theming, caching, 10

## Background

I am developing a custom theme for my Drupal 10 site. I found myself constantly flushing the cache, so I have been looking up ways to disable the cache on my local dev site. My end goal is to be able to simply refresh the page to see CSS changes. I need this in order to enable live reload at a later step.

## Problem

I am having extreme difficulty disabling the cache, despite reading multiple Drupal docs and q/a's on stack overflow and stack exchange.

## Attempts

I tried many attempts outlined below over the past day and a half and each attempt failed. I also restarted Apache service after each attempt.

### Attempt 1

I found [this Drupal doc](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/disable-caching#s-disabling-twig-caching-the-easy-way) and tried the steps:

1. I disabled caching on the Admin interface. This included going to **Admin -> Configuration -> Development -> Development Settings** and toggling all of the options to on.
2. When this didn't work, I went to **Admin -> Configuration -> Performance** and changed Caching to `<no cache>`.

### Attempt 2

I tried the solutions in the [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272377/disable-caching-of-attached-css-js-libraries-for-custom-module) mine was closed as a duplicate of. This question said this was due to Apache caching static files but didn't explain how to fix this. I found this [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891965/how-to-disable-cache-of-apache) that explained how to modify the `.htaccess` file to disable caching. I added the below config to my `.htaccess` file in my root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

- Made sure that my `httpd.conf` is loading mod_rewrite
- Added EnableSendfile off to `httpd.conf`

### Attempt 3

I tried the other answer on [the question used to close mine](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272377/disable-caching-of-attached-css-js-libraries-for-custom-module) which recommended to remove `version: VERSION` from the `info.yml` file. I also read through the posted [blog](https://chromatichq.com/insights/drupal-libraries-version/). I tried removing the line as it recommended but this did not work.

I read through the string of q/a's and blogs which suggested removing VERSION from the `libraries.yml` file which also didn't work.

### Attempt 4

As per a comment on my first question, I added `$settings['deployment_identifier'] = 'A1234';` to my `settings.php` file.

### Attempt 5

I followed the steps [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/disable-caching#s-configure-settingslocalphp) created a `settings.local.php` file. I added the below:

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;

$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

## Conclusion

After all of these failed attempts, I don't understand what I am missing and I really want to learn how to fix this. I am open to any possible solutions or things I haven't tried.

## Additional Info

I previously posted [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317002/does-disabling-the-drupal-cache-also-disable-the-css-cache?noredirect=1#comment406518_317002) but it was closed as a duplicate and linked to a solution that doesn't even fix my issue which is pretty frustrating. Seeing that it wasn't reviewed and reopened, I decided to submit a new question with much more detail so that hopefully this one isn't simply closed.

- This is in a local development environment on my computer not an external host
- I am not using the color module which is known to cause similar issues
- Stack Exchange suggested [this similar answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54951/cant-disable-css-caching-and-aggregation), but it also didn't help

Comment: What tool are you using for your local dev? Lando, DDEV, Docker Compose, XAMPP ???

Comment: For testing purposes, you could try uninstalling "Internal Dynamic Page Cache" and "Internal Page Cache" and if it's still cached then something is up with your environment.

Comment: Maybe it's your browser?

Comment: I configured Apache with virtual hosts to serve the web folder, but I don't use any other tool to run the site. I have also tested this on Chrome, FF and Edge with the same problem. I'm also going to try these testing steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the isolated fixes didn't work for me. After many more attempts, I was finally able to find a solution that works for me, and it turned out to be a combination of most of my attempts.

1. Go to `settings.local.php` and uncomment the following. Make sure the first two options are set to false:

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;

$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['page'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

**Note:** If this file doesn't exist, you copy & paste `example.settings.local.php` from `web/sites` into `web/sites/default` and rename it to `settings.local.php`. Once this is done, you can make the above stated changes.

2. In your `settings.php` file, uncomment the section:

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
  include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

Otherwise the `settings.local.php` file will not be seen or used.

3. Go to your site and navigate to the **Admin Toolbar -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance**. Ensure that Aggregate CSS files and Aggregate JavaScript files are both disabled.

**Note:** I am not sure why this was needed though. For me, this did not work until I disabled these and cleared the cache manually.

4. Add the following to your `/web/.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I tested removing this and it broke the refresh, so it appears that this is needed at least in Drupal 10.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely the browser as commented by @No Sssweat. Clearing the browser cache should load a new version of static CSS files. Also putting the browser in dev mode or configuring the webserver to send headers not to cache the files.

This is only Drupal-specific because Drupal is adding a query string to CSS files so they can be invalidated on code updates or a full cache clear:

```
<HTML ...>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/core/.../align.module.css?xyz123" />
    ...
```

See [CssCollectionRenderer::render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Asset%21CssCollectionRenderer.php/function/CssCollectionRenderer%3A%3Arender)

However, you should be able to use this for your custom theme as well, when Drupal render caching is already disabled and you are building a new page HTML structure on each request anyway. Generate a new cache-busting query string for each page:

*mytheme.theme*

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $cache_settings = \Drupal::service('settings')->get('cache', []);
  if (isset($cache_settings['bins']['render']) && $cache_settings['bins']['render'] == 'cache.backend.null') {
    _drupal_flush_css_js();
  }
}
```

I've included a check for the local dev settings (Attempt 5). For two reasons, (a) it needs these settings to work properly and (b) it shouldn't run in a production environment.

This is not a solution for everyone. Web designers have tools to live edit CSS files. They are, as explained at the beginning, just files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but unfortunately it still didn't work for me. I also tried multiple browsers so I don't think it was browser issue, however I did manage to resolve this issue. I posted my solution.